# Ubuntu Contacts and Google - how to sync?

Tags: 13.10, google, contacts, online-accounts

I would like to use the contacts app in Ubuntu to pick up and sync with my Google contacts.  This way they will be there on my phone and my other computers.
I see no way to do this.

Can anyone help and tell me how to sync the two together and keep them updating each other?

Comment: Are you sure you save the contact in your android device in google? Normaly it saves them by default in the phone.

Comment: @AngelSalinasHuerta Mine have always synced back to my Google account (SGS2, N5)

Comment: Then you mean your contacts to show up in the Emphaty IM client or Friends app? Your google contacts can only appear in the Gnome Mail Client (evolution) as (sic.) mail contacts.

Comment: Not Empathy, not Evolution, not Andoid.  I am talking of the Gnome-Contacts program which is installed with Ubuntu.  I select it, am given the choice of local or online account.  I choose online and find myself with no ability to add the Google address book.  The Online Accounts section of System Settings don't offer any option either.  I am stuck.  If I can get the Google Contacts into the Contacts application then I will have my phone and computer contacts in both places.

Comment: I can recommend using **Thunderbird Address Book** with **gContactSync** Addon as an alternative (and probably better working) solution.

Comment: @markrich Gnome-contacts uses EDS (evolution-data-server) as backend. Install evolution. Sync google-contacts with evolution. You can even use [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/) for advance sync. Your contacts will appear in Gnome-Contacts.

Answer (score 3):

Well there are two *Online Accounts* Apps in Ubuntu:

- *Ubuntu Online Accounts*. This one is for the Unity Desktop and is pre installed in Ubuntu.
- *Gnome Online Accounts*. This one is for the Gnome Shell Desktop and is **not** pre installed in Ubuntu.

The `gnome-contacts` App is a Gnome Application and therefore uses the *Gnome Online Accounts* App. But you use the *Ubuntu Online Accounts*, which curiously do not link the Address book of the Google Account.

### Install the *Gnome Online Accounts* in Unity

Install *Gnome Online Accounts* with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts
```

After that you must activate the *Gnome Online Accounts* for the Unity Desktop [[Source]](https://askubuntu.com/a/145309):

Change in the file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop
```

the line from

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

to

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

After that you should see two *Online Accounts* in *System Settings* and in Unity Dash. Add your Google account also to the *Gnome Online Accounts* and you should be able to see your Google Contacts in the `gnome-contacts` App (perhaps you must change your Address Book in the menu of `gnome-contacts` with *change address-book* to the google address-book of you choose *local address-book* before).

#### EDIT: Since Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Since Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty the `gnome-control-center` where you open the Online Accounts was [replaced by `unity-control-center`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity-control-center). Therefore trying to open the *Gnome Online Accounts* in Unity will fail with `** (unity-control-center:13209): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "online-accounts"` (If you lunch `gnome-control-center`, `unity-control-center` will be opened instead). It seems not to be possible to open the *Gnome Online Accounts* in Unity anymore. However you can

- install `gnome-shell`
- log into the Gnome Shell Desktop
- Adding Account to *Gnome Online Accounts*
- Remove `gnome-shell` again if you want

then the Google Account Contacts will also be available in Unity in `gnome-contacts`

Comment: Is this answer up to date?

Comment: Yes. In Ubuntu 14.04 *Ubuntu Online Accounts* still not integrate into `gnome-contacts`, but the control-center has changed, see *EDIT: Since Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty*.

Comment: gnome-contacts doesn't connect to thunderbird (running 18.04)